# Iterate through object in svelte

Tags: loops, object, iteration, reactive-programming, svelte

I am using svelte and was wondering why this won't log anything? is it something to do with reactivity? I am trying to iterate over an object...If there is any more code needed to tell, let me know thanks!

```
let videoElement: HTMLVideoElement;
$: captionLines = [''];
$: console.log('captionLines', captionLines);

       if (videoElement && videoElement.textTracks) {
            console.log(videoElement.textTracks);
            if (videoElement.textTracks.length >= 0) {
                    //get to this point...
                Object.keys(videoElement.textTracks).forEach((key) => {
                    //nothing logs here...
                  console.log(key, videoElement.textTracks[key]);
            });
           }
```

[image: code]

LOG[image: result]

Comment: Do *not* screenshot text. Both of these screenshots are unnecessary and inaccessible.

Comment: okay. I thought it would be nice to see the output i'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

The tracks are a list, using `Object.keys` on such an object will likely only return `['length']` or other irrelevant property names. The prototype of `TextTrackList` defines an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), this means you can loop through the tracks using `for ... of`:

```js
for (const track of videoElement.textTracks) {
  console.log(track.label, track.language);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to log anything either.

Comment: Use a debugger to more closely inspect the state during execution. It is not clear when and how often your code runs. If the list is empty it will definitely not log anything.

Comment: thank you for helping, I think I found a solution below!

Answer (score 0):

after reviewing/debugging my code, I found that the cues would be empty, and I needed to listen to them change/update first. using this I was able to find the cue information i needed.

```
    //Detect the cue tracklist...
        videoElement.textTracks.onchange = (event) => {
            //Get the first track...
            let track = videoElement.textTracks[0];
            track.mode = 'hidden';
            if (isCaptionsEnabled) {
                track.mode = 'showing';
            } else {
                track.mode = 'hidden';
            }
            //Detect cues and cue info...
            if (track) {
                track.oncuechange = (event) => {
                    //Get first activecue...
                    let cue = track.activeCues[0];
                    if (cue) {
                        // console.log('video duration', duration);
                        // console.log('cuestart', cue.startTime);
                        // console.log('cueEnd', cue.endTime);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
```